# Trigonometric Series Function

Tags: functions, summation, contest-math

I came across a function where we have to find $n$ where they give us two separate values $a$ and $b$.

The function is:

$$f(n) = 2\cdot7^{n/2}\cdot\cos(n\theta) + n\cdot4^n,\text{ where }\theta = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$$

The summation is:

$$\sum_{n=a}^{n=b} f(n)$$

With the values of $a$ and $b$, I just need to figure out what the value of the summation will be.

Comment: What is $n$ in this context? It's definitely used as an index of summation, but you said in the beginning that you're trying to find $n$. Maybe you meant to say that you're trying to find the sum?

Comment: Yes, I would find the sum. I'm sorry for the confusion! I just need to find the value of that summation.

Comment: I'd recommend editing your post to clarify this.

Comment: Use Euler's formula, a simple derivative, and the sum of a geometric progression, and you should get the result